# How to order Django Tables2 column by model property that depends on outside model query

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

Say I have two models, one with a property:

```
class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Name_ID(models.Model):
    name_id = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def object_name(self):
        try:
            return Name.objects.get(id=self.name_id)
        except Name.DoesNotExist:
            return ''
```

Then I try making a table using django-tables2 for the Name_ID model only:

```
class NameIDTable(tables.Table):
    object_name = tables.Column()

    class Meta:
        model = Name_ID
        row_attrs = {'data-id': lambda record: record.pk}
        exclude = ('name_id',)
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-striped', 'style': 'display: block; overflow: auto;'}
```

The table successfully shows the object_name column with all of the values from the property. However, when I try clicking on the column header for it so I can order them by name, I get an error because 'object_name' is not an actual field in the Name_ID model. Many of the solutions I found don't work because they assume that you're using fields from the model itself, not queries from outside models. How do you make the table orderable by the object_name property?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has a page on this: [custom ordering](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/ordering.html#table-order-foo-methods).

That said, you should tell django-tables2 how to order the query, that's not something django-tables2 can do for you, as the implementation of your property is opaque to django-tables2. In your example, things would be easier if the `name_id` column were a `models.ForeignKey`, and not `models.IntegerField()`, but I assume you have a reason to do so.

If you know how to sort the query, you can write an `order_object_name` method, like explained in the docs.

Comment: Tried that. Not sure how to integrate outside model queries with that.

Comment: what exactly are you referring to with 'that' now?

Comment: I tried using the order_object_name method but model queries don't work well with it.